# How to capture a JDialogs window closing event in a JFrame

Tags: java

I have a major JFrame running my application. It calls a JDialog class to perform a utility function, after performing its function, the user closes the dialog. I want the JFrame to detect that the JDialog has been closed. In other words how do I fire an event from the dialog when it's closed, and then catch it on the JFrame. Thank you.

Comment: I think you can add a `WindowListener` to it, which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a WindowListener and add it to the JDialog. The logic you seek after the JDialog is closed can be placed in the windowClosed or windowClosing method of the WindowListener. See the [Window Listener Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) at Oracle for more information on how to implement this listener. Below is an example using the WindowAdapter class (empty implementation of a WindowListener) with the windowClosed method overridden:

```
myJDialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
        myJframe.doSomething();
    }
});
```

Comment: Than you for your answer, but the problem is how to catch the jdialog's window closing event in the jframe. Because I want the jframe to detect and take a certain action once the jdialog is closed. Kindly include an example if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Post edited, but without specifics related to your code it is quite abstract. The windowClosed will be called by the EDT when the JDialog is closed. Just add the WindowListener to the JDialog from a location where your JFrame object is accessible, and from there you can call its methods or access it's variables as needed

Comment: Have gotten a useful idea from the myJframe.dosomething() suggestion/post. Lemme giv it a try.. Thanks a lot all.. Truly appreciate

Answer (score 1):

you should add a Window Listener to your JDialog

```
jdialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    System.out.println("jdialog window closed event received");
}

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    System.out.println("jdialog window closing event received");
}
});
```

If you want the event be handled directly by a specific object, this object should implement the WindowAdapter. for example your jFrame.